Computation of a height of an algebraic number
It is an exercise from an algebraic number theory book: Let $y\in{\overline{\mathbb Q}}^\times$. Prove that there exists $C>0$ that for for all $n\in\mathbb N$, the Weil height of $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{y^k}{k!}$ is less than $C\delta^nn!$ where $\delta$ is the least positive integer such that $\delta y$ is an algebraic integer.
What I wrote is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{y^k}{n!}=\frac1{\delta^nn!}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!\delta^{n-k}}{k!}{(\delta y)}^k$$
where $\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!\delta^{n-k}}{k!}{\delta y}^k$ is an algebraic integer. So for every non archimedean place $v$, on a
$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!\delta^{n-k}}{k!}{(\delta y)}^k\right|_v\le1.$$
But I am stuck at here. I do not manage to conclude from what I wrote. Maybe it was a bad idea or something is missing. Any answer or help is welcome. Thanks in advance.
